# Discord.py - Finding information about the sender

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a simple discord bot and am trying to find out the channel and sender of a message, so for example when someome types `d!salute blah` it will reply with `"<SENDER> saluted blah!"`, accompanied by an image. I currently only really know how to use `client.say`, which finds the channel for me. What I want to know is how to retrieve both the channel a message is sent from and also the sender of the command. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass context so you can access the message object.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True) #passing context
async def salute(ctx): #context gets passed into the first parameter
    print(str(ctx.message.author))
    print(str(ctx.message.channel)
    print(str(ctx.message.content))
```

And so on, you can find out more on the message object at [The docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)

Comment: Could you tell me how I would find what role the person who sent the message has?